# Call Skrollr refresh() after transform

Tags: javascript, html, skrollr

I am trying to learn how tu use Skrollr making small transitions and movements.

I want to transform one element and after that, move it to the top op the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="test" data-0="transform:scale(1)" data-1000="transform:scale(0.25); top:35%" data-1500="top: 0%"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#test {
    background: red;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    left: 35%;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
}
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var s = skrollr.init({
        render: function(data) {
            document.querySelector('.scrollpos').innerHTML = data.curTop;
        }
    });
    //s.refresh($('#test'));
}
```

If I use transform-origin: 0 0, it works well (top does not change) but if I use default (transform-origin: 50% 50%) the top position of the element changes and I need to use top: -XX% to place the element at 0% position.

I think the solution is to call:

```
s.refresh($('#test'));
```

in my code as I commented inside the code (or s.refresh()) but it does not work and my element only moves some pixels near of top.

I need to call refresh() in other place or in different way?

Thanks!

---

Edit:

Example 1 - Move one element to top (no problems)

```
data-500 = top: 35% | data-1000 = top: 0%
```

http://cokeperez.com/stack1.html

Example 2 - Scale element and move to top (element does not move to the top)

```
data-500 = top: 35%, scale: 1 | data-1000 = top: 0%, scale: 0.25
```

http://cokeperez.com/stack2.html

Example 3 - Scale element and move to top adjusting value (not perfect but it works)

```
data-500 = top: 35%, scale: 1 | data-1000 = top: -5%, scale: 0.25
```

(Same link with stack3.html, I can't post more than 2 links)

Comment: I don't quite understand the issue. Also I don't think you need `refresh`. Could you create a demo page?

Comment: Thanks for reply @Prinzhorn. And thanks for Skrollr too :).

Sorry, maybe my explanation in english is a bit confusing. I have added some examples. I hope you can understand my problem now.

Thanks again!

Comment: Would it work for you to animate from scale(4) to scale(1) instead? This way you won't have problems aligning the top.

Comment: Yes, it works. But I want to use an image and scale(4) shows image with very low quality.

I discard this effect for now and I continue testing other options.

Thanks again @Prinzhorn!

Comment: I'm not sure how browsers will handle it, but you could easily use `width` and `height` to first downscale the image by 1/4